# How to detect and block USB device

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project which is used to detect and block Removable USB device on connection.
I just need the code for scanning of USB devices that are connected.

Comment: Do you have anything at all to work with?

Comment: have you did any work around????

Comment: I didn't have any code right now. Just want some sample code for detecting USB devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey
    Dim ver As Decimal
    'opens the path USBSTOR from regedit
    If rbtnDisable.Checked Then
        If MsgBox("All USB Ports Will Be Disabled Except The Presently Connected Ports (Ex.,USB Mouse,Printer etc !) ", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "ARE YOU SURE ?!") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", True)
            regKey.SetValue("Start", 4) ' 4(To disable the ports)
        End If
    Else
        regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", True)
        regKey.SetValue("Start", 3) ' 3(To enable the ports)
        MsgBox("Ports Are Enabled !", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End If
End Sub
```

I use this code to `block/enable USB Port(s)`

and refer [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c727e48-9319-400b-8bef-52541e130771/how-to-detect-an-inserted-or-removed-drive?forum=vbgeneral),[2](http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2009/11/10/vb-net-detecting-when-a-usb-drive-is-connected-and-getting-the-drive-letter/) links for detecting USB Drives

Answer (score 1):

get [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)

```
   process.start("devcon /r disable USB*")
```

much more easier

Comment: I am a noob. Please explain me more.